# Non-negative matrix factorization

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement NMF on Python, and below is what I found on Google:

```
def matrix_factorization(R, P, Q, K, steps = 500, alpha = 0.0002, beta = 0.02):
Q = Q.T
for step in xrange(steps):
    for i in xrange(len(R)):
        for j in xrange(len(R[i])):
            if R[i][j] > 0:
                eij = R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j])
                for k in xrange(K):
                    P[i][k] = P[i][k] + alpha * (2 * eij * Q[k][j] - beta * P[i][k])
                    Q[k][j] = Q[k][j] + alpha * (2 * eij * P[i][k] - beta * Q[k][j])
    eR = numpy.dot(P, Q)
    e = 0
    for i in xrange(len(R)):
        for j in xrange(len(R[i])):
            if R[i][j] > 0:
                e = e + pow(R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j]), 2)
                for k in xrange(K):
                    e = e + (beta/2) * ( pow(P[i][k],2) + pow(Q[k][j],2) )
    if e < 0.001:
        break
return P, Q.T
```

When I run the code, some of the values are negative, which can't be according to the definition of the technique.

I noticed that the error term **eij = R[i][j] - numpy.dot(P[i,:],Q[:,j])** is not an absolute value,

so I tried eij = numpy.fabs(eij), which returns **RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars**.

Other methods that returns an absolute value (e.g., math.abs(), etc.) don't work either.
Please help me with this!

Comment: There are available NMF libraries out there, for example: http://nimfa.biolab.si/

Or are you implementing this as an exercise?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I was too desperate to just implement the code I found from Google. The thing is, NIMFA does not work properly when I simply copy and paste the example code on the main page. I think the example is somewhat wrong (for I had to modify the import part)... Have you tried the library?

Comment: No - unfortunately I did have an NMF.py library at some point, I dont remember if it is NIMFA or not, but I no longer have access to the machine so I cant confirm or not, sorry.